# EMACS increase TRAMp speed

Tags: emacs, tramp

after updating to Aquamacs (EMACS 24.4.1) the speed for copying files from remote to local with `TRAMP` really went down. Of course I know that `TRAMP` is not really fast for that, but it didn't used to be so sluggish (takes minutes to copy 5MB to local).
I've tried setting `tramp-default-method` to scp snd ssh but no big difference for me...

Any suggestions of how to increase the `TRAMP` speed are very welcome.

Also I was wondering if the `encode/decode base64` is really necessary for copying files and if not how to switch it off.

Cheers, F

Answer (score 2):

Tramp's traces include timestamps. You might set tramp-verbose to 6, and rerun your tests with the different Tramp (Emacs) versions. This might show, where the time is eaten.

If you don't want to publish the traces publicly, send them to me; I could check.

Comment: Thanks for your response! For now I've fixed my problem by reverting to Aquamacs 3.0a, where TRAMP 2.2.9-pre works - for some mysterious reason - way faster. I'll maybe try to upgrade again after Christmas, than I'll probably get back to you :)